# Kustomize: How to cause a generator to actually merge an object instead of duplicating

Tags: kustomize

I'm using `kustomize` to manage my `argocd` manifests.

My structure looks like this:

```
argocd
├── base
│   ├── argocd-ui-ingress.yaml
│   └── kustomization.yaml
└── overlays
    └── dev
        ├── argocd-cm-patch.yaml
        ├── argocd-repo-server-ksops-patch.yaml
        ├── ksops-secret-generator.yaml
        ├── kustomization.yaml
        └── secret-argocd-notifications.yaml
    └── prod
        ├── argocd-cm-patch.yaml
        ├── argocd-repo-server-ksops-patch.yaml
        ├── ksops-secret-generator.yaml
        ├── kustomization.yaml
        └── secret-argocd-notifications.yaml
```

This is my `overlays/dev/kustomization.yaml`  file:

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/v2.3.2/manifests/install.yaml
- ../../base

patchesStrategicMerge:
  - argocd-cm-patch.yaml
  - argocd-repo-server-ksops-patch.yaml

patches:
- patch: |-
    - op: add
      path: /spec/rules/0/host
      value: argocd.foo.com
    - op: add
      path: /spec/tls/0/hosts/0
      value: argocd.foo.com
  target:
    kind: Ingress
    name: argocd-ui

generators:
  - ksops-secret-generator.yaml
```

This is my `ksops-secret-generator.yaml` file:

```yaml
# Create a local Kubernetes Secret
apiVersion: viaduct.ai/v1
kind: ksops
metadata:
  name: ksops-secret-generator
files:
  - secret-argocd-notifications.yaml
```

And lastly, my `secret-argocd-notifications.yaml` looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
    name: argocd-notifications-secret
    namespace: argocd
data:
    foo: [ENC]...
```

Since it's a `sops`-encrypted file, I'm using [ksops](https://github.com/viaduct-ai/kustomize-sops) plugin to generate the usable Secret resource.

The problem that I'm having currently, is that the remote resource I'm using (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/v2.3.2/manifests/install.yaml), already includes a Secret named `argocd-notifications-secret`. So when I run `kustomize build overlays/dev --enable-alpha-plugins`, I get two Secret resources named `argocd-notifications-secret`. One from my local file that gets generated through the `ksops-secret-generator`, *and* the one that is included in the remote manifest.

I tried to solve this by adding the `replace` (and also `merge`, got the same result) behavior annotation to my local file:

```yaml
    annotations:
        kustomize.config.k8s.io/behavior: replace
```

But ended with this error:

```
Error: merging from generator &{0xc000d4c0a0 <nil>}: id resid.ResId{Gvk:resid.Gvk{Group:"", Version:"v1", Kind:"Secret", isClusterScoped:false}, Name:"argocd-notifications-secret", Namespace:"argocd"} does not exist; cannot merge or replace
```

I also can't add my local file under `patchesStrategicMerge` section, because then it just adds the raw `sops` encrypted file (without using the `generator` at all).

Is there a way to handle that scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this was all a red-herring.
The main issue turned out to be the `namespace` directive that was on the `argocd-notifications-secret` overlay. After removing it, I re-added the below annotation:

```yaml
    annotations:
        kustomize.config.k8s.io/behavior: merge
```

And it worked.

Credit to this quick turnaround is due to the CNCF Slack #argo-cd channel. [Thread here](https://cloud-native.slack.com/archives/C01TSERG0KZ/p1649195475769299)